# cannot do xcodebuild - Scheme has a space

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, xcode9.4

The Scheme that I need to do the test has a space in it, e.g. "Abc Test"

When I setup CI job, and do xcodebuild, will get error [xcodebuild: error: Unknown build action 'Test'.]

I tried to pass that name as a parameter (-scheme $testScheme), but still not works. Can anyone please help? many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting the scheme name in double quotes?

e.g. `xcodebuild -scheme "Abc Test"`

Answer (score 0):

you can escape the space by putting a '' in front of the space, e.g.:
"Abc\ Test".
I think you should use <> instead of "", but I'm not sure, so like this:
<Abc\ Test>.